# How wait for returnvalue of a messagebox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calling procedure that calls my messagebox and expects a returnvalue:

```
text = 'do you want?';
buttons = Array('Yes','No','Perhaps');
param = Array(text,buttons);
returnvalue = msg(param);

alert(returnvalue);
```

this calls the function that fills the messagebox. after filling it shows the message box. So far it works.
BUT: it does not wait (after show) for generating and returning the chosen value. where and how do I implenemt the callback?

```
function msg(arr) {
    var text = arr[0];
    var buttons = arr[1];
    $('#modal-text-msg').html(text);
    out = '';
    for (i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(buttons[i]);
        out += '<input type="button"  class="modal-button modal-button-msg" value="'+buttons[i]+'">';
    }
    $('#modal-close-msg').html(out);    
    $('#modal-msg').show();

    $('.modal-close').on('click', '.modal-button-msg', function(e) {
    returnvalue = $(this).val();
    $('#modal-msg').hide();
    return returnvalue;
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a callback function. Javascript doesn't have a sleep or wait command. Even if it did, bad things happen when Javascript isn't allowed to move on. Try changing up `msg` to look like:

```
function msg(arr, callback) {
    var text = arr[0];
    var buttons = arr[1];
    $('#modal-text-msg').html(text);
    out = '';
    for (i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(buttons[i]);
        out += '<input type="button"  class="modal-button modal-button-msg" value="'+buttons[i]+'">';
    }
    $('#modal-close-msg').html(out);    
    $('#modal-msg').show();

    $('.modal-close').on('click', '.modal-button-msg', function(e) {
        returnvalue = $(this).val();
        $('#modal-msg').hide();
        if (callback instanceof Function) callback(returnvalue);
    }); 
}
```

There was no need to `return returnvalue;` because that was returning it to the event handler and not to the caller of `msg`. The caller has already moved on. Now you'd call `msg` like so:

```
msg(param, function(value) {
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Ogbum this works fine ... thanks!!!  But if i call it more than one time it increases the alerts... Is that beause the instanceof ???

Comment: `instanceof` just makes sure we know what `callback` actually holds (this won't throw an error if you were to call `msg(params, 6)`). What "it" exactly are you calling multiple times?

Comment: lets say I have mutliple buttons on my page the user can click and is asked what to do. now I press some of it and get even more alerts...

Comment: That may warrant it's own question.

Comment: Yes you are right!!!  Found it. It was the eventhandler. Solved it with:  `$('.modal-close').off('click').on('click', function() { });`